# Meta data doesn't work on the client, only on the server response

Tags: next.js

```
<Head>
    <Seo
      title="Home, Sweet Home"
      description="Home, Sweet Home Description"
    />
  </Head>
```

Above you can see how I use `next/head` component to show seo meta data on my page, below you can see Seo component

```
function Seo({ title, description, ogTitle, ogDescription }) {
  return (
   <>
     <title>{title}</title>
     <meta name="description" content={description} />
     {ogTitle && <meta property="og:title" content={ogTitle} />}
     {ogDescription && (
       <meta property="og:description" content={ogDescription} />
     )}
   </>
```

)
}

And what problem I see, here in source code , I see my meta data

[image]

but , I don't see those data on the client side

[image]

as you can title is emprty , why does it happens ?

Comment: If your question has been answered, please make sure to accept an answer for further references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [docs says](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/head):

> title, meta or any other elements (e.g. script) need to be contained as direct children of the Head element, or wrapped into maximum one level of <React.Fragment> or arrays — **otherwise the tags won't be correctly picked up on client-side navigations**.

You either need to remove `Seo` wrapper component, or add `<Head>` tag inside of it:

```js
function Seo({ title, description, ogTitle, ogDescription }) {
  return (
   <Head>
     <title>{title}</title>
     <meta name="description" content={description} />
     {ogTitle && <meta property="og:title" content={ogTitle} />}
     {ogDescription && (
       <meta property="og:description" content={ogDescription} />
     )}
   </Head>
}
```