# Next/Head won't render meta tags inside of Fragment

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, next.js

I am in process of making a small SEO library for my website. It's available as [`@peuconomia/react-meta-tags`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@peuconomia/react-meta-tags) publicly.

Now, the library is working fine from my perspective. As `<SummaryCard />` component is currently wrapped by one Fragment with 5 meta tags as children. Now, in Nextjs code below. I am trying to print the meta tags using the `<SummaryCard />` component. But, the head will not render the component.

Nextjs documentation reports that the Head component will render inside it at most one Fragment deep component. The `<SummaryCard>` works fine when used on main, but not from Head.

How to make it work inside of `<Head />`.

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import Image from 'next/image'
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.scss'
import {SummaryCard} from "@peuconomia/react-meta-tags/lib/twitter";

export default function Home() {
    return (
        <div className={styles.container}>
            <Head>
                <SummaryCard
                    title={'Title'}
                    description={'Nothing to see here'}
                    imageAlt={'Image of Pokimane.'}
                    site={'@peuconomia'}
                    imageUrl={new URL('https://google.com/image.jpg')}
                    key={'twitter'}
                />

                <title>Learn to Code</title>
                <meta name="description"
                      content="freecodeuniversity.com. A place to learn all about the web. We teach you all the programming language(s) including HTML*, CSS and Javascript. We also teach about both NoSQL and SQL databases."/>
                <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico"/>

            </Head>

            <main className={styles.main}>



                <h1 className={styles.title}>
                    Welcome to <a href="https://freecodeuniversity.com">Learn to Code!</a>
                </h1>



                <p className={styles.description}>
                    Get started by editing{' '}
                    <code className={styles.code}>pages/index.tsx</code>
                </p>

                <div className={styles.grid}>
                    <a href="https://nextjs.org/docs" className={styles.card}>
                        <h2>Documentation &rarr;</h2>
                        <p>Find in-depth information about Next.js features and API.</p>
                    </a>

                    <a href="https://nextjs.org/learn" className={styles.card}>
                        <h2>Learn &rarr;</h2>
                        <p>Learn about Next.js in an interactive course with quizzes!</p>
                    </a>

                    <a
                        href="https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/master/examples"
                        className={styles.card}
                    >
                        <h2>Examples &rarr;</h2>
                        <p>Discover and deploy boilerplate example Next.js projects.</p>
                    </a>

                    <a
                        href="https://vercel.com/new?utm_source=create-next-app&utm_medium=default-template&utm_campaign=create-next-app"
                        className={styles.card}
                    >
                        <h2>Deploy &rarr;</h2>
                        <p>
                            Instantly deploy your Next.js site to a public URL with Vercel.
                        </p>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </main>

            <footer className={styles.footer}>
                <a
                    href="https://vercel.com?utm_source=create-next-app&utm_medium=default-template&utm_campaign=create-next-app"
                    target="_blank"
                    rel="noopener noreferrer"
                >
                    Powered by{' '}
                    <span className={styles.logo}>
            <Image src="/vercel.svg" alt="Vercel Logo" width={72} height={16}/>
          </span>
                </a>
            </footer>
        </div>
    )
}
```

**EDIT:**

> title, meta or any other elements (e.g. script) need to be contained
> as direct children of the Head element, or wrapped into maximum one
> level of <React.Fragment> or arrays—otherwise the tags won't be
> correctly picked up on client-side navigations.

This is what Next.js suggests. It must be direct children of Head but is no problem if I add one Fragment to it as well. And, I am adding only one fragment to it at the moment.

Comment: Check if an user is using Next.js or not, if they are then selectively wrap the content inside your summary card in `next/head` instead of [the fragment here](https://github.com/ExpertKiD/react-meta-tags/blob/624258e3d4a01a5ea6229c651e0c58d89190aea4/src/twitter.tsx#L13). Then advice the users (in docs) to directly use your component outside `next/head` if using Next.js (the way the new next/script component does). For the first part you can refer this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68368065/11613622 -- It'll be pretty straightforward for `next/head` actually.

Comment: You'll also need the above for `PlayerCard` and `AppCard` too. For the latter, you may face some complications due to nesting of `head`s.

Comment: Yes I have already added the PlayerCard and AppCard as well. I am refactoring it right now, so it will be available soon. But, I wanted to not wrap around next/head directly, as it would make next.js a dependency for other projects that do not use next.js. If this is the case, then I'll have to think about calling it react meta tags. Instead call it nextjs-react-meta-tags.

Next.js said wrapping around one fragment is OK, However, the Fragment doesn't seem to render on the `<Head/>`.

Comment: No, it will not make Next.js a dependency for other projects that don't use Next.js. That's what the linked answer was about. You'll just make it an optionalDependency. If the user is using it then use `next/head` otherwise don't. For the latter part, wrapping in a fragment only works if the fragment is a direct child(ren) of `Head`, which is not in your case, as it is being injected by your custom component.

Comment: Related: [Meta data doesn't work on the client, only on the server response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68508779/11613622)

Comment: I have updated the component. Please add it as answer as it works now. I used ComponentType as type and add the container. https://www.npmjs.com/package/@peuconomia/react-meta-tags.